# How do you continue your program even if an exception occurs?

Tags: java, exception

In my program I have to constantly access the hard drive thousands of times to view images (no way around it), occasionally my program gets tripped up on a "file not found IO Exception" most likely because of the many modifications I'm making to the images and re saving quickly. How do I continue my program even if this error occurs, because currently it causes my program to stop?

Code:

```
filepattern=imageLocation+temp+"image.jpg";
File outputfile = new File(filepattern);

BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(outputfile);
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Note: I have fixed the problem by making sure the file exists first. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Depends on how you are handling the exception. Posting code would help us give a meaningful answer.

Comment: Post some code showing your issue.

Comment: What happens when the exception is caught (besides silently sweeping the exception under the rug and leaving you with a null `img`)?

Comment: I can't see this constructor in api `new File(outputfile)`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. So basically, I'm constantly taking pictures of a changing picture online and then I remove a portion of the picture and resave it then read the picture and analyze the picture. However sometimes there is the error when reading the picture as I explained and it stops taking pictures.

Comment: so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329568/how-to-continue-the-java-program-after-exception and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712745/continue-execution-even-after-program-catches-exception couldnt help

Answer (score 1):

Catch the exception and handle it as needed.

```
try {

// your code

} catch (<Expected exception> e) {
// handle the exception
}
```

Comment: Silently swallowing exceptions is a really bad idea.

Comment: I understood "eat" to mean "handle", but perhaps the more aggressive downvoter will retract if you change `print if needed` to `handle the exception`

Comment: I'm just curious, what is the difference between this and the normal catch exception?

Comment: @user3341249: Not a thing. It's pretty much what you now have posted in your question.

Comment: @user3341249 are you calling the code again after the exception? Post some more detailed code like from where it is getting called.

Comment: I tried to retract my down vote but it wouldn't let me. I guess your edit was under the time limit where the system registers the post as edited. Try making a dummy edit. I still don't really believe this helps the OP though since they seem to be asking about how to handle the exception, not just catch it.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the statement with a `try` `catch`.

This will stop the code from crashing and in the `catch` block you can write code to deal with the failure.

Comment: Yes I did that, however it continues to freeze up when that error happens.

Comment: @user3341249: Then you're going to have to give us more information about what you've tried (like actual code).

Comment: Basically it tries to read a file that does not exist because it is still saving from a previous method. It throws an IO Exception since the file does not exist then it stops doing what it is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 key words
try {}
executes the block that can cause problems
catch (Exception ex) {}
executes code to handle specific exceptions. Instead of Exception you can handle specific exception types
finally {}
executes cleanup code. Even if exception occurs and breaks the execution flow in try block, this code will always execute.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like the fragment below.  Of course, you will want to encapsulate the actual reading in a try / catch / finally block to make sure you close the file

```
try {
    filesTried++;
    [you code]
} catch (IOException e) {
    fileErrors++;
```